# bloginfo('template_url') - produces different result

Tags: wordpress

I have a site and it is working in localhost mode. However, when I upload the site, the second CSS doesn't load.

I'm using

```
bloginfo('template_directory');
```

to read some second CSS and also to read my js file

```
<link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style/<?php echo $estilo_cor_variavel; ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/site.js"></script>
```

The js file is working, but the CSS isn't.

They produce different paths.

```
<link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="/site/wp-content/themes/site/style/padrao/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<script src="http://site.com.br/wp-content/themes/site/js/site.js"></script>
```

I don't know why the same function produces different results.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be adding your CSS or JS using the `<link>` or `<script>` tags directly. Instead you should enqueue them from your functions.php. Your function might look something like this:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', ' enqueue_scripts ' );
```

Comment: +1 && just a notice: to set a script/css for a particular page you can use `is_page('myPage_or_PageID')` / `is_single()` / `is_archive()` whatever ... to save requests/performance

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_template_directory_uri()` function instead:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()>/js/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/site.js"></script>
```